# How to disallow *fill* of unused memory?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

I have a memory section defined in my linker file, but I have not placed any variables in that section (Since, I would like to use this section only through pointers).

My problem is, when the .map file is generated it fills all these unused areas with 0s. (even without providing any fill command in linker file).

`*fill*         0x10022222   0x033c00 00`

I do not want it to get filled with 0s. I want those memory locations to retain the value what it contains. How do I command to not generate this fill ?

Edit 1: This is a MRAM location (mem mapped) not the primary memory - hence it will retain the value and OS should not really be bothered to erase it.

Edit 2: It is a cross-GCC compiler (DDCI) for PPC architecture. A proprietary OS  is running. I can give any specific details of the OS.

Comment: Are you trying to bake a block of memory into an executable and then use some pointers to start reading from it?

Comment: If the OS allows it, that would be a security issue. I think there's good reason that it behaves this way; it's likely the implicit default.

Comment: Are you sure there's code running that actually zeroes out this memory, or are you just getting mapped to a (COW-copy of the) standard zero page? Remember that a normal user program does not see real memory.

Comment: "This is a MRAM location (mem mapped) not the primary memory" - I can't fathom the reason why you still fail to mention the platform, since this si obviously platform specific.